# Verify any property changed from object with dozens of properties in C# from the client side

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

To determine if an object changed that came from a C# object, we have to test each property individually like below.  Is there a way to get a single value from the C# object, that is easy, without doing all these comparisons and use it on the client.  The property could be some sort of hash that would only change if any values on that object changes.  `GetHashCode` by itself seems to change, even if the object's properties are the same.

The properties below came from this C# object and we test if it changed individually, but want to know if anything changed to show a highlight of that item on the client.

```
self.updated = ko.pureComputed(function () {
                return self.pts.isModified() || self.f.isModified() || self.ast.isModified() || self.reb.isModified() || self.ft.isModified() || self.fg3.isModified() || self.fg.isModified() || self.inGame.isModified();
        });
```

Comment: You can implement INotifyPropertyChange and notify when some of them changes. Yes, you have to write lot of setter and getters and creates an event but with reflection and imagination you may do easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can override GetHashCode and compare Hash Codes of new and initial objects:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 57;
    var props = GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var p in props)
    {
        if (p.GetValue(this, null) != null)
            hash = 27 ^ hash ^ p.GetValue(this, null).GetHashCode();

    }
    return hash;
}
```

There is even better solution. You can mark properties, which you want to track, with an Attribute:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hash = 57;
            var props = GetType().GetProperties();

            UInt32 crc = 0;
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                if (!p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(YourAttribute), true).Any())
                {
                    if (p.GetValue(this, null) != null)
                        hash = 27 ^ hash ^ p.GetValue(this, null).GetHashCode();

                }
            }
            return hash;
        }
```

This way you will be able to include\exclude some properties form the tracking.

Comment: But that goes back to my original issue.  I dont want to do this for say 100 properties.

Comment: You can go thru all the properties in a loop. I have updated the example

Comment: If you don't want to manually update every property, your best option is to write a script that does it for you. Or if you REAAAALLY want to make things a nightmare for your future self, and anyone else who ends up needing to use this code. You can copy your object, and then use reflection to iterate over every property of the original, to see if any of the values have changed since you last took a copy.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should notify by the PropertyChanged event when you uses the SetProperty method:

```
 class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int MyProp { get; protected set; }
        public string stringProp { get; protected set; }

        public void SetProperty(string propertyName, object value)
        {
            var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

            var property = properties.ToList().Where(x=> x.Name == propertyName ).FirstOrDefault() ;

            if (property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(this, value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            }
        }

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.  
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName  
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.  
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

**Example of use:**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var cl = new Class1();
            cl.PropertyChanged += propertyChanged;

            cl.SetProperty(nameof(cl.MyProp), 1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void propertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (e.PropertyName);

        }
    }
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2